# How can I check that I'm not frying the chipset on my 945 gclf?

Tags: cooling

I'm running an old 945 gclf as a home server. Its an odd little system which has a passively cooled single core atom 230 processor, and a small heatsink/fan combo over the chipset.

[image]

lm-sensors/sensors detects one temperature sensor which I guess is the processor.

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +38.0Â°C  (crit = +100.0Â°C)
```

The fan on it is making rather horrible noises and I am considering unplugging it or using a speed reducer. There's also a risk it may fail anyway.

Is there any way I can monitor the temperatures of the chipset or be warned of any issues with it? Is there anything specific I can watch out for that would indicate trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about removing the CPU fan and not replacing it?  If so, don't!  From the picture, it looks like a standard fan that you could buy for like $5.  Having the fan directly on the CPU cools MUCH better than having one at a distance and also blows some air over the chipset.  Make sure the fan is blowing down towards the CPU.  It also doesn't hurt to have another fan to blow air over the motherboard in general to vent the air outside the case.  Generally a fan in the back of the case pulling air out is best.  The only way to monitor the temps on the chipset is if the mobo has a sensor on it or if you have an external sensor.  Many fan control products have this feature (usually a piece of hardware that goes in an external drive bay).

According to the spec sheet it only has thermal sensors for the CPU. Not for the chipset. So you would need an external device with a sensor that attaches to the chip. There usually is not a good place to attach it since the heatsink fully covers it. You can attach it to the bottom of the heatsink, closest to the chip, but it won't be as accurate. The temps shown will be lower than the actual chip temp.

Comment: Yeah, this specific generation of atom is odd. The bigger heatsink and fan are for a 945GC chipset. If you're bored enough, there's complete system specs [here](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15990/eng/D945GCLF_TechProdSpec.pdf). I've slowed it down with a speed reducer off a noctua fan which seems to work, but the original question still needs answering

Comment: Do you know the exact size of the fan?  www.frozencpu.com has an excellent selection of fans.  With molex connector starting at 25mm.  With PWM (connected to motherboard same as yours) starting at 40mm.  (I didn't see the fan size in the spec sheet)

Comment: I'm not particularly inclined to replace the fan (and I'm sure I can get one locally). I'd like to *monitor* the system primarily, especially if I choose to experiment,

Comment: I answered it in my first answer.  "The only way to monitor the temps on the chipset is if the mobo has a sensor on it or if you have an external sensor. Many fan control products have this feature (usually a piece of hardware that goes in an external drive bay)."